# How can I show the "loading"-spinner animation in SAP Commerce Cloud/Hybris Backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I show and hide the default "work in progress"-spinner animation in SAP Commerce Cloud Backoffice via Java?

Is there an existing method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

To display the spinner :

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("zAu.cmd0.showBusy();");
```

To hide the spinner :

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("zAu.cmd0.clearBusy();");
```